# react native installation of expo cli npm error

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

Guys please help me how to fix this error in my system.
Im running the commands in ubuntu wsl.

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xcpretty/node_modules/@babel
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/@babel
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/svgo/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tar/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tempy/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/p-locate/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/terser/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/to-object-path/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@wry
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/union-value/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/postcss-merge-rules/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/stylehacks/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/unset-value/node_modules/has-value/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/unset-value/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/update-check/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/url-loader/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/url-parse-lax/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/url/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/spdy-transport/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/util/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/anymatch/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/braces/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fill-range/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/is-number/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/anymatch/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/express/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/glob-parent/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/globby/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/braces/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fill-range/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/is-number/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/send/node_modules/debug/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/send/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-log/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/braces/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fill-range/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/is-number/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpackbar/node_modules/chalk/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpackbar/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/wide-align/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/workbox-build/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/worker-loader/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/copy-concurrently/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/move-concurrently/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/pumpify/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xcode/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/npm-pick-manifest/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/yargs/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.3.3 requires a peer of react-refresh@^0.8.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@babel/compat-data
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@babel/compat-data'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@babel/compat-data'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@babel/compat-data'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/paul/.npm/_logs/2021-06-08T02_41_40_218Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be you don't have write access and therefore cannot add new node modules into the `/usr/lib/*` directory. A simple fix could be to add `sudo` infront of your command.

```
sudo npm install expo-cli
```